# Using wijmo event calender with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, wijmo

Hell, I'm trying to use the wijmo event calender with the AngularJS liabry, but the appointments binding isn't working correctly.
This is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Control Tests</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/rocket/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet"
              title="metro-jqueryui" type="text/css" />

        <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/globalize.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/angular.wijmo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="../../Scripts/Controller/MainController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".wijevcal").wijevcal();
            });
        </script>

        <div ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
            <div class="wijevcal" appointments="{{calAppointments}}"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the source of the Controller:

```
function MainController($scope)
{
    $scope.calAppointments = [{
        start: new Date(2013, 5, 23, 15, 30)
    }];
}
```

Can someone tell me, why the start date isn't applied to the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the Wijmo module in order to use the custom directives provided by Wijmo.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on my own.

I had to call

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["wijmo"]);
```

at the beginning of the script and now I can use the tag

```
<wijevcal></wijevcal>
```